# Git flow: Can I publish a feature more than once before I finish the feature?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm beginning to use git flow. I have created a feature:

```
git flow feature start eval
```

then I did some work and added and committed changes:

```
git add (files)
git commit -m "(description of commit)"
```

I hadn't finished the feature, but wanted to push it to an external repo to back it up for the night:

```
git flow feature publish eval
```

Ok, no problem so far. Now I'm working again, and I'd like to push some new changes to the external repo, but I'm still working on the feature. But when I run

```
git add (new files)
git commit -m "(description 2)"
git flow feature publish eval
```

it returns

```
Branch 'origin/feature/eval' already exists. Pick another name.
```

But my branch is `feature/eval`, so if I pass another branch name to `git flow feature publish <name>`, it will throw an error.

In summary, my question is this-- How do I push multiple commits when I'm in the middle of (not ready to finish) a feature? Can I just run something like `git push origin feature/eval`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `git-flow` extension checks that the branch name [doesn't already exist](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/0.4.1/git-flow-feature#L372) to prevent you or someone else from accidentally overwriting it. It also [configures your branch](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/0.4.1/git-flow-feature#L379-L380) to track the remote branch you just `publish`ed, so you can now just `git push` whenever you have more changes.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify so that I understand. I should use `git flow feature publish <name>` to push my first commit on that feature branch. Afterward I just use `git push` with no branch specified. Then for the final commit and remerge I use the `git flow feature finish <name>`-- correct?!

Comment: Yep, that should do it! If someone else is working with you on the branch, you can also use `git pull` normally.